# Unable to Retrieve DS4 Controller Power Level in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sdl

I'm working on a Python project where I need to retrieve the power level of a DualShock 4 (DS4) controller using Pygame. Although Pygame recognizes the DS4 controller, I cannot seem to find a method to get the power level information.

Here's a simplified version of the code I've tried:

```
import pygame

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Initialize the joystick
pygame.joystick.init()

# Check if any joystick is connected
if pygame.joystick.get_count() > 0:
    my_joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    my_joystick.init()

    # Attempt to get power level information
    if hasattr(my_joystick, 'get_power_level'):
        power_level = my_joystick.get_power_level()
        print(f"Power Level: {power_level}")
    else:
        print("Power level information not available.")
else:
    print("No joystick connected.")
```

The issue is that the get_power_level() method doesn't seem to be available for the DS4 controller. I've also tried the inputs library, but it throws a UnpluggedError: No gamepad found even though Pygame recognizes the controller.

Is there a way to retrieve the power level of a DS4 controller in Pygame, or is there an alternative library or method that I should consider?

Comment: This is not a problem with the code, but with the hardware or driver.

Comment: I have a few questions: a) What's your pygame/SDL version (it is printed in the console), b) Why are you using ``my_joystick.init()`` - it has been deprecated, c) Is your pygame version newer than ``2.0.0dev11`` - in that version ``Joystick.get_power_level()`` was added. You are definitely doing something wrong - even if there is no power information available, ``Joystick`` will still have the ``.get_power_level()`` method - it will just return "unknown". That's why I'm guessing that you are using an ancient version of pygame, can this be the case?

Comment: Sources: [documentation](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/joystick.html#pygame.joystick.Joystick.get_power_level), [implementation](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/ad182e79524e20d2e0ee091922084b1104455581/src_c/joystick.c#L248C9-L248C9).

Comment: @oBrstisf8o I write the question wrong. In fact `.get_power_level()` always returns "unknown".

Comment: @FrostDream Could this be related to [this](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/5933) issue in SDL github repo?

Comment: So this is a bug in Pygame/SDL, but a problem with the code.

Comment: @FrostDream What version of pygame/SDL do you have? A comment in the issue I provided claimed that upgrading SDL to 2.0.20 fixed the issue.